# Is it possible to make a foreach loop for fields in a class using IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

I was wondering if it would be possible to make the fields of a class enumerable so you could iterate over them with a for or foreach loop. I have seen a few versions describing how to make a structure containing other structures be enumerated in that way.

I am also aware I may have completely misread the [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8) on the subject.

So my question is, is it possible to iterate over fields in a class using IEnumerable or a similar Interface?

I would like to do something like this:

```
private class Integers
{
    public int int1;
    public int int2;
    public int int3;
    public int int4;
    public int int5;
    public int int6;
    public int int7;
    public int int8;
}

foreach(int I in Integers){
    Console.WriteLine(I); 
}
```

Comment: It is possible to do with Reflection, but the fact that you want to do this may be an indication that you shouldn't be using a class at all. Would a List be more appropriate? Or a Dictionary?

Comment: Shouldn't you start by implementing `IEnumerable` on your class?

Comment: @RufusL Implementing IEnumerable is almost certainly a bad idea, all this needs is a property containing a list, or just replace the entire thing with a list/dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to iterate over fields in a class, using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.reflection).
Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int I1;
    public int I2;
    public int I3;
    public int I4;
}
// typeof(MyClass).GetFields() return FieldInfo[], which is IEnumerable<T>
foreach (var field in typeof(MyClass).GetFields())
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
}

// I1
// I2
// I3
// I4
```

However, you should probably use something else. An array might be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an enum: [enum docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: How would an enum help here?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with Reflection:

```
var Integers = new Integers{
    int1 = 50,
    int2 = 42,
    // etc. ...
};
foreach (var field in typeof(Integers).GetFields())
{
    Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(Integers));
}
```

But the fact that you want to do this may be an indication that you shouldn't be using a class at all.

Do you want an enum?

```
private enum Integers
{
    int1 = 50,
    int2 = 42,
    // etc.
}

foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Integers)).Cast<int>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Would a List be more appropriate?

```
var integers = new List<int>() { 50, 42, /*etc*/};
foreach (var value in integers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Or a Dictionary?

```
var integers = new Dictionary<string, int>() { 
["int1"] = 50, 
["int2"] = 42, 
/*etc*/
};
foreach (var keyValuePair in integers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Value);
}
```